# Problem controlling common cathode 12V RGB LED

Tags: led, 12v, led-driver

I want to be able to control an RGB LED with common cathode and I've used the circuit below for each colour. For some reason there is 12V on the output all the time and I can't control the LED as it's switched on all the time.

[image: Circuit]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the voltages you apply to O1?

Comment: also, your circuit is **direly** missing a series resistor for your LED.

Comment: The voltage on O1 is 5V. The series resistor is already in the LED (it's a button with RGB LED inside)

Comment: then please add the resistor to your schematic – otherwise, the schematic is incomplete (you're using a "diode" symbol, not an "LED with series resistor" symbol, which afaik doesn't exist).

Comment: You neet 0V on O1 which should produce 12V on Q? gate to turn the LED off

Comment: ... also, please use the function of your schematic editor to assign actual numbered names to your components, otherwise it's hard to talk about your schematic's components.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've updated the schematic now. Added the resistor and the numbers to the components.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I've tried blinking it, but it stays on all the time. I've measured the voltages and they are almost the same 11.67V when LOW and 12.04V when HIGH.

Comment: @Cezerb are you sure you're using the right symbol for Q12? Is that maybe a P-channel MOSFET with a body diode? If it is (check with the datasheet of that MOSFET!), put in the correct symbol (as in the datasheet, probably) instead of what you're using, and your question will probably answer itself!

Comment: As Marcus says, Q12 is backwards on the schematic. But if you aren't getting a bigger swing on Q12 gate, you aren't turning Q11 on. But it should turn on at 5V. It looks OK on the schematic but is it reversed on the PCB?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've checked the datasheet and there is indeed a body diode going from drain to source. Correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand the current goes through this diode and thus the MOSFET is kind of useless and does nothing.

Comment: @Cezerb exactly, so you either need to use an N-Channel mosfet or swap drain and source, and then see whether your turn-on voltages are so that they're useful to you.

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Body diode of Q12 is conducting permanently in your circuit. To avoid such mistakes use schematic symbol with diode drawn inside the mosfet. [Link to datasheet of the mosfet](http://aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO3401A.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

P_chanel mosfet should be connected source to "+ ", drain to resistor r14.turn it over